# Uploading image to mongoldb from ionic

Tags: mongodb, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I am trying to store the image from ionic to mongoDB.

As long as I have R&D there are to major method they have used..

- Upload the image to server using Multer and stored the references in mongodb(They have not stored the image in mongodb just the references.)
- The image is stored in the mongoDB as buffer using the command

  ```
  var imgPath = '/path/yourimage.png';

  mongoose.connect('localhost', 'testing_storeImg');

  var schema = new Schema({
  img: { data: Buffer, contentType: String }
  });

  var A = mongoose.model('A', schema);

  mongoose.connection.on('open', function () {
  console.error('mongo is open');

  A.remove(function (err) {
   if (err) throw err;
   console.error('removed old docs');

  // store an img in binary in mongo
  var a = new A;
  a.img.data = fs.readFileSync(imgPath);
  a.img.contentType = 'image/png';
  a.save(function (err, a) {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.error('saved img to mongo');
  ```

  If the image is bigger the above method takes time.

Are there any better method to store the image in mongoDB.

Comment: Have you considered GridFS? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/

Comment: Thanks for the update.. even I also ended in that solution only..